# Having problems with Macro running every 15 minutes correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code (See below) which is suppose to run the code every 15 minutes so that my data is refreshed from yahoo finance and recorded in the appropriate cells. The macro is suppose to run on its own once I run it for the first time. It will run the first time after 15 min then it will start doing it every 2 min then back to 15 min. It isn't consistent. Below the code is a picture of what it is producing.

```
Sub TimeStamp()
'
' TimeStamp Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
' Following refreshes the data
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild

' Following Inputs Exchange Date (L1) and Time (N1) into next available cell in column A
With ActiveSheet
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value = Application.Evaluate("CONCATENATE(L1,N1)")
        .WrapText = False
    End With
End With

' Following inputs the current price of stock (G3) into next available cell in column D
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("G3").Value2
End With

' Following inputs the date of the exchange (L1) into next available cell in column B
With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'this sets the value of B2 with the value of L1
    .Value = ActiveSheet.Range("L1").Value2
    .WrapText = False
End With

' Following inputs the Time of the exchange (N1) into the next available cell in column C
With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'this sets the value of B2 with the value of L1
    .Value = ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Value2
    .WrapText = False
End With

' Following runs TimeStamp macro every 15 minutes
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "TimeStamp"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Where does the code say to run every two minutes? I just see the 15 minute wait part.

Comment: that's what I am confused about. It is suppose to only run every 15 minutes but occasionally it will run with a gap of 2 minute or sometimes even 1 minute between runs

Comment: is it possible that when I reopen the workbook that it will start running the macro again from when I last used it thus running the macro as if it were two separate macros?

Comment: I'm guessing those "extra" runs were scheduled from a previous run of your macro.

Comment: @TimWilliams is there a way to end all macros currently running?

Comment: @THAT newbie  I would try to make sure it is creating the request correctly.  When you set it up to run in 15 minutes, output what is being setup so you can compare it to when it is running.  It might be that you need to build the Application.OnTime request different.  May need to change now + Timevalue() part.

Comment: You need to capture the value of `Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")` in a global variable so you can use the same value to cancel the OnTime call.

Comment: Still new to VBA... just read a bit on Global variable but I'm still not 100% sure on why and how to declare the global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global variable means it is accessible to any routine or function in the macro. You declare a variable global by doing it outside (above) the rest of the code.

[Chip](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx) has an excellent tutorial that should address your issue.

Declare Public variables in a standard code module, outside of and before any procedure (Sub or Function) declaration:

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 120 ' two minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "TheSub"  ' the name of the procedure to run
```

To start a repeatable timer, create a procedure named StartTimer as shown below:

```
Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0,0,cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

This stores the time to run the procedure in the variable RunWhen, two minutes after the current time.

Next, you need to write the procedure that will be called by OnTime. For example,

```
Sub TheSub()
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Your code here
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    StartTimer  ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub
```

This procedure executes whatever code you include in it, and then at the end calls the StartTimer procedure to schedule another OnTime event. This is how the periodic calls are implemented. Note that if you close the workbook while an OnTime event is pending, Excel will re-open that workbook to execute the procedure and will not close the workbook after the OnTime event is finished.

Comment: Wow, 95% of this is over my head but I am going to use Chip and hopefully it will work for me. Thank you for the link, it helps when learning VBA.

Comment: Please improve this answer. A global variable is accessible from any routine in a VBA PROJECT. Class modules, for example, would likely never be considered a MACRO. Likewise most professional code is not either. But even accepting your definition, you then go on to advise declaring public variables before any procedure in a standard code module. You never make the link that these are global for THAT newbie. And,,, of course, public or private variables can be at the top of any module, not just standard codes modules. Your wording implies constants are variables... they are not. Your subs...

Comment: ...are not declared public or private, which is odd when matched with your point on public variables.